# "datalabels" property applied to all "datasets"

Tags: reactjs, charts

I've been working on the front end bit recently on one of the projects at work and I got a bit of a problem. We're displaying a graph on the website, which shows some realtime data pulled from the database.

This is the code that has been written to create the graph:

```
const weeklyBarData = {
  labels: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Pens Assembled',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(200,10,10,0.8)',
      borderColor: 'transparent',
      datalabels:{
        align: 'end',
        anchor: 'end',
        formatter: function(value, context){
          let percent = (totalPensDaily[context.dataIndex] !== 0 ? (value / totalPensDaily[context.dataIndex])*100 : "");
          percent = Math.round(percent);
          percent = (percent !== 0) ? percent.toString() + '%' : "";
          return percent;
        }
      }
    },
    {
      label: 'Pens Disassembled',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(10,200,10,0.8)',
      borderColor: 'transparent',
      datalabels:{
        align: 'end',
        anchor: 'end',
        formatter: function(value, context){
          let percent = (totalPensDaily[context.dataIndex] !== 0 ? (value / totalPensDaily[context.dataIndex])*100 : "");
          percent = Math.round(percent);
          percent = (percent !== 0) ? percent.toString() + '%' : "";
          return percent;
        }
      }
    },
    {
      label: 'Pens Claimed',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(10,10,200,0.8)',
      borderColor: 'transparent',
      datalabels:{
        align: 'end',
        anchor: 'end',
        formatter: function(value, context){
          let percent = (totalPensDaily[context.dataIndex] !== 0 ? (value / totalPensDaily[context.dataIndex])*100 : "");
          percent = Math.round(percent);
          percent = (percent !== 0) ? percent.toString() + '%' : "";
          return percent;
        }
      }
    },
  ],
};
```

As you can see in the code there, I had to copy the code related to "datalabels" three times, and I want to avoid that. I've read in the Chart.js documentation that you can apply "datalabels" to each dataset, whole chart or globally, and I believe in our situation applying this to a chart would be the best solution. I tried to add "datalabel" code behind the array, but still within `datasets` and it didn't work. I also tried to redesign the `weeklyBarData`, but I had some errors that wouldn't even load a website correctly, I tried to do something like this:

```
const weeklyData = {
  labels: [],

  datasets: {
    data: [
      {
        // logic goes here
      },
      {
        // logic goes here
      },
      {
        // logic goes here
      }
    ],
    datalabels: {
        // logic goes here
    }
  }
};
```

I run out of ideas and I can't find any solution online, hence me question: Is there any way for me to either redesign the `weeklyBarData` code or apply the `datalabel` property to the whole chart using te current code?

(We use React for our front end).

Secodnly, using the code provided above I am able to create this graph:

[image]

As you can see, I get that weird little thing in the top-left corner. I zoomed at it and it seems like some string with "%". Also, it disappears when I remove all `datalabel` code. Any thoughts on what that could be and how to get rid of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to apply the labels to the entire chart,
add `datalabels` to the plugins option...

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("data");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: weeklyBarData,
  options: {
    plugins: {
      datalabels:{
        align: 'end',
        anchor: 'end',
        formatter: function(value, context){
          let percent = (totalPensDaily[context.dataIndex] !== 0 ? (value / totalPensDaily[context.dataIndex])*100 : "");
          percent = Math.round(percent);
          percent = (percent !== 0) ? percent.toString() + '%' : "";
          return percent;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

see following working snippet...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var totalPensDaily = [100, 100, 100, 100, 100];

  const weeklyBarData = {
    labels: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Pens Assembled',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(200,10,10,0.8)',
        borderColor: 'transparent',
        data: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
      },
      {
        label: 'Pens Disassembled',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(10,200,10,0.8)',
        borderColor: 'transparent',
        data: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
      },
      {
        label: 'Pens Claimed',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(10,10,200,0.8)',
        borderColor: 'transparent',
        data: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
      },
    ],
  };

  var ctx = document.getElementById("data");
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: weeklyBarData,
    options: {
      plugins: {
        datalabels:{
          align: 'end',
          anchor: 'end',
          formatter: function(value, context){
            let percent = (totalPensDaily[context.dataIndex] !== 0 ? (value / totalPensDaily[context.dataIndex])*100 : "");
            percent = Math.round(percent);
            percent = (percent !== 0) ? percent.toString() + '%' : "";
            return percent;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.2.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="data"></canvas>
```

note: I don't see any *weird little thing in the top-left corner* here...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It definitely makes things clearer and I will try to deploy them. Our code looks slightly different, and from what I can see we pass the data for the bar within `render()` and it looks like this: 
`<WeeklyOverview weeklyBarData={weeklyBarData} weeklyBarOpts={weeklyBarOpts} />`.

Inside 'WeeklyOverview.js' we create each chart Bar separate (?), by doing this:
`<Bar data={this.props.weeklyBarData} options={this.props.weeklyBarOpts} height={350} />`.

I will probably have to edit code a little bit to adapt your suggestion.

Comment: Also, the little-weird thing is between "500" on y-axis and the text `Weekly Overview` - on the photo.